# Is it possible to add refernece to global parameter in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to add a reference to a global parameter in an operation in swagger doc in below manner, but couldn't figure out a way to do this in swashbuckle.

```
"paths": {
   "<path>": {
   "post": {
         "parameters": [{"$ref": "#/parameters/<globalparam>"}]
           }
     }
  }
```

I checked out NonBodyParameter() but it doesn't have ref field defined. Is it possible to achieve this via Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?

Comment: This can be accomplished by post-processing using IDocumentFilter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62782119/how-to-use-swashbuckle-to-generate-global-parameters-in-the-resulting-swagger-fi